# Is their any way to call ember-selectize action into controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-select

I am new to ember development. I have to call action on the ember-selectize, 
but I am not getting where to write that action code?

//template

```
{{ember-selectize
          id = property
          content = studentNames
          optionValuePath = "content.id"
          optionLabelPath = "content.name"
          placeholder = "Select a name"
          select-item=(action 'displayStudentName')
       }}
```

//Can we write the method displayStudentName in controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Did it not work for you? Btw IIRC bindings can't have spaces in between them content = studentNames => content=studentNames

Comment: thanks for the comment. it works.

Comment: Did it not work because of the "x  =  y" thingy?

Comment: yes, using you can called displayStudentName method in controller.but i defined one variable and assigned that variable to value attribute of the ember-selectize and write observer on it.

Answer (score 0):

For select-item you only have to pass in the name of the action as a string.

`select-item='displayStudentName'`